# Application Verifier reports and error in the VS Console: Deleting critical section with invalid lock count

Tags: windows, multithreading, mutex, critical-section

I opened **appverif.exe**, added my binary to the list and enabled the "Basics" tests. After saving the changes I opened the application in debug mode with Visual Studio. More precisely I first started the service (the application is a service which runs as SYSTEM so I need to attach to it later) and then I attached the VS debugger to the process.

Sometimes the application crash just after `DeleteCriticalSection` and the following message is displayed in the VS Console window:

```
VERIFIER STOP 00000208 - Deleting critical section with invalid lock count
    05AAEB48 : Critical section address. Run !cs -s <address> to get more information.
```

I suppose that this means that the `CRITICAL_SECTION` variable has been deleted while another thread had a lock on it. Is that correct ?

How can avoid such problem ?

I know that the ideal tool would be a reference counter so that only who owns the last reference to the pointer delete the object. This is already implemented in C++11 and later but not in pure C.

A mitigation might be to register every thread which use the variable for the first time. When a thread wants to delete the variable it first checks if the queue contains only its id and if that's the case the deletion is completed otherwise demanded to the last thread in the queue. Of course the variable might be still used by a thread who never used it so this thread has not been registered to the queue yet and can still call `EnterCriticalSection` on the variable and cause a crash. Another problem is that you need to protect the queue access (at least the write access) with another `CRITICAL_SECTION` variable so you are just moving the problem from one variable to another.

Any idea ?

Comment: Nice hint but ...how can I do that ? Unfortunately I didn't design this application so it's also difficult to figure out what is the design flaw. It's also difficult to control what threads still has a reference to the `CRITICAL_SECTION` and can call `EnterCriticalSection`.

Comment: That's why in my opinion the only way to fix this is to use a pointer object with a reference counter. Since I can introduce and successfully compile C++ code in this pure C application I will go for it. Unfortunately I can't use C++11 because the application is cross compiled and not all compilers supports this version. Anyway I don't think it's so difficult to implement a class like this. I found a nice sample here:
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/c-shared-ptr-and-how-to-write-your-own-d0d385c118ad